# Most efficient way of selecting closest point

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, geospatial

I have two (very large) tables of identical structure, holding two types of locations :

### LocA

- Id - INT
- X - FLOAT (latitude)
- Y - FLOAT (longitude)

and

### LocB

- Id - INT
- X - FLOAT (latitude)
- Y - FLOAT (longitude)

Each of them hold several million rows. I need to select all locations in LocA and for each location, the closest location in LocB.

What would be the most efficient query to do this?

EDIT1 : The distance algorithm would be a dumb one : SQRT(POWER(LocB.X - LocA.X, 2) + POWER(LocB.Y - LocA.Y, 2))

EDIT2 : An implementation that I've done but I'm really not sure if it's optimal (I highly doubt it), would be :

```
SELECT  A.Id    AS AId,
(   SELECT TOP 1 B.Id
    FROM    B
    ORDER BY SQRT(POWER(B.X - A.X, 2) + POWER(B.Y - A.Y, 2)) ASC
)               AS BId
FROM    A
```

EDIT3 : It's common to have "duplicates" in table LocB but I would want any of the matching "closest" to be returned for a location in LocA, not all.

Comment: Using what algorithm for "closest"? There are many

Comment: Also, when you say "very large" how large are you talking? Some people's "very large" are other people's "meh"

Comment: Tens of millions. At least 10 million each.

Comment: @Jamiec: Don't _meh_ too early. We are still talking about 10,000,000² calculations.

Comment: How would you handle equidistant points? Return all matching points? Just one? Also, is this a one-off or a recurring query?

Comment: @MichaelMilom : regarding equidistant points, choose any of the equidistant point, no problem.

Comment: Are there any crude heuristics that you can apply to whittle the set or potential matches down at all - i.e. is there a certain distance above which you don't care about matches, and how widely distributed is the data?

Comment: I suggest you examine [spatial datatypes and indexes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933790%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for such queries.

Comment: This specific page will be of most interest to you: [Query Spatial Data for Nearest Neighbor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929109.aspx)

Comment: For the record : I do not downvote answers to my own questions no matter what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about :

```
SELECT id as Aid,x,y,m % 100 as bId
FROM (
SELECT A.id,A.x,A.y,MIN(CAST(((A.x-B.x)*(A.x-B.x)+(A.y-B.y)*(A.y-B.y)) AS BIGINT)*100+B.id)     as m 
FROM A
CROSS JOIN B
GROUP BY A.id,A.x,A.y) j;
```

Comment: This is not returning duplicate distances.

Answer (score 2):

This is not likely to be very efficient, but at the moment I can't see a better way:

```
SELECT  a.ID, a.X, a.Y, b.ID, b.X, b.Y, b.Distance
FROM    LocA a
        CROSS APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 WITH TIES
                    b.ID, 
                    b.X, 
                    b.Y, 
                    Distance = SQRT(POWER(b.X - a.X, 2) + POWER(b.Y - a.Y, 2))
            FROM    LocB b 
            ORDER BY Distance
        ) B;
```

Comment: This has a problem and if two points have same distance one of them are returned.

Comment: @AmirrezaKeshavarz Corrected to resolve the problem of ties, if there are ties it will return all records.

Comment: This is pretty much equivalent to the OP's query - except it provides the `WITH TIES` option to be added.

Comment: @ypercube Yes, the edit had not been done when I started my answer, and due to the position of the answer box on my page I could not see the flag that indicated the question had been edited, so by the time I had seen what the OP had put I had already posted the answer. It also has the added benefit of allowing the distance and the ID to be returned in a single query, were it not for this I would have removed it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought to take into consideration [geography::Point](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964711%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), [STDistance](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933808%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) method, and create a [spatial index](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933796%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) on those points columns?

If your database structure is fixed, you can add a new persisted computed column.

Answer (score 1):

The SQRT is not going to change the ORDER - it is just overhead

```
SELECT  A.Id AS AId,
(   SELECT TOP 1 B.Id
    FROM    B
    ORDER BY POWER(B.X - A.X, 2) + POWER(B.Y - A.Y, 2) ASC
)               AS BId
FROM    A
```

I am thinking there is a way to perform two passes
You know the distance is <= delta X + delta Y
And the maximum error in that approximation is SQRT(2) - 1

This does not deal with duplicates or ties

I suspect the extra IO is not going to make up for the reduced number of POWER calculations but it might be worth a try
Only worth a try if you have #temp on SSD

```
create #temp1
IDa
IDb
Xa
Ya
Xb 
Yb 
distSum
distAct 

insert into #temp (IDa, IDb, Xa, Ya, Xb ,Yb, distSum)
select a.ID, b.ID, a.x, a.y, b.x, b.y, abs(a.X-b.X) + abs(a.Y-b.Y)
table as a 
join table as b 
on a.ID < b.ID 

delete #temp 
from #temp 
join 
(select IDa, min(distSum) as minDistSum from #temp group by IDa) as aMin 
on #temp.IDa = aMin.IDa 
and #temp.distSum > 1.414*(minDistSum) 

update #temp 
set distAct = POWER(Xa - Xb, 2) + POWER(Ya - Yb, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code :

```
WITH S AS (
SELECT *
FROM LOCA CROSS APPLY( select locb.id as ID_B, (POWER(LocB.X - LocA.X, 2) + POWER(LocB.Y - LocA.Y, 2)) D  FROM LOCB ) S
)
SELECT DISTINCT ID,X,Y,d,ID_B
FROM S
where d=(select min(d) from s s1 where s1.ID=s.id)
```

Comment: good answer but i think the OP wanted the closest location (lat/long), not the minimum distance.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I would need the ID of the location in LocB, also. However, thank you for taking the time to construct it!

Comment: Why use a windowed function in `SELECT DISTINCT ID, X, Y, MIN(D) OVER(PARTITION BY ID) FROM S` instead of the more traditional `SELECT ID, X, Y, MIN(D) FROM S GROUP BY ID, X, Y;`? The two are synonymous (assuming ID is the primary key) with the latter being more efficient and (in my opinion) more readable.